# Can't connect from Python Docker to mqtt Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mqtt, mosquitto, docker-network

So I've got a toke/mosquitto docker container running to which I can connect from outside docker.

Then I'm using a Python docker container that should publish data to my mosquitto broker. Here's my code:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as paho
import time
import random

broker = "localhost"
port = 1883


def on_publish(client, userdata, result):
    print("Device 1 : Data published.")
    pass

client = paho.Client("admin")
client.on_publish = on_publish
client.connect(broker, port)

for i in range(20):
    d = random.randint(1, 5)

    # telemetry to send
    message = "Device 1 : Data " + str(i)
    time.sleep(d)

    # publish message
    ret = client.publish("/data", message)

print("Stopped...")
```

The code works trying to connect to a mqtt broker not running in docker.

But I can't figure out how to let both run with docker and connect to each other. My error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pub_client1.py", line 15, in <module>
    client.connect(broker, port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 937, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1071, in reconnect
    sock = self._create_socket_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3522, in _create_socket_connection
    return socket.create_connection(addr, source_address=source, timeout=self._keepalive)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

Im already using a docker network. What am I missing?

Thanks already for the help :)

Comment: The mqtt server is your computer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by Felipe, localhost will not work when using docker. You must change
`broker = "localhost"` to point to the service you defined on your docker compose file for mqtt or to the IP address of mqtt when running on different network.

If your docker compose file references mqtt as mqtt (`mqtt: build mqtt:latest`) then you need to change your broker variable to `broker = "mqtt"`

Comment: Thanks for the help. That did the trick. I tried it this way before but I must have had a mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

That code is trying to connect with **localhost**. A container is like another computer, therefore when you use **localhost** you are connecting with the container itself.

You have to connect that code with the computer where mqtt serve are running. You can try use the explict IP of that computer or use a DNS if you have one.

Comment: Thanks, I just got it working using the container id, I tried it with the mqtt image name before but that doesnt seem to work. How do I have to define the name?

Obviously I need this when subscribing to a broker running on the same machine and not publishing

Comment: That's is another big issue, you have to define somehow your machine with a name in a docker network. I'm don't find anything like this in docker docs. I think that the best way to approach this is using another container.

Comment: Maybe the problem with 2 containers that you had is the same thing. A good pratice is use the container terminal and try to ping the other container. When you are in a docker network the container DNS is the same of the container name.

Comment: yeah thats the plan :)  Thanks for the help

Comment: Good to know. Definitely will use it in the future